# Can I construct a set from the linear combinations of elements in a basis of $\mathcal{V}$ to form a basis for any subspace $\mathcal{W}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a vector space,  $\mathcal{W}$ be a subspace of $\mathcal{V}$, and **B** be the set of all basis for $\mathcal{V}$. Then:

$\forall$ $B$ $\in$ **B**, $\exists$ a set $S$ composed of linear combinations of $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$ $\in$ $B$ $\ni$  $S$ is a basis for $\mathcal{W}$.

Say I select some random basis of $\mathcal{V}$ and some random subspace $\mathcal{W}$. Can I construct a set that is composed of linear combinations of elements in the basis of $\mathcal{V}$ to form a basis for $\mathcal{W}$?

Here's my thought: since all of the elements of the subspace are also an element of the vector space, it must be that any basis of the subspace is made up of elements that are themselves linear combinations of any basis of the vector space.

Comment: You're right, working on it, I think it is right now.

Comment: ok I think it communicates what I want to ask now.

Comment: As it if formulated now, the set $S$ may be taken to be any base of $W$ (for each $B$), as each basis of $W$ consists of linear combinations of a basis of the full spaces. But it is still confusing.

Comment: It is confusing, I am still learning how to write math correctly. The set $S$ is the basis of $W$ that corresponds to the random basis $B$ of $V$ that I chose. It seems to me that I should be able to choose any basis of $V$ and form a new set that is composed entirely of linear combinations of elements in $B$, this new set would be a basis for $W$.

Comment: I don't understand "the bases **that corresponds** to the **random** basis...". How does it correspond? You may take this an exercise to work out proper formulations. Sometimes even constructing the right question can help you to understand the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Fix a basis $B$ of $V$. Pick any basis $S$ of $W$. As every basis vector in $S$ belongs to $V$, and since $B$ is a basis for $V$, we can express each basis vector in $S$ as a linear combination of vectors in $B$. Therefore you have found a basis $S$ for $W$ which consists of linear combinations of elements in $B$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. So I should be able to express every vector in S as a linear combination of vectors in B since every vector in S is in V and B spans V.

Comment: @JosiahBlaisdell Correct.